# Getting Fn::GetAtt error in the AWS SAM template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have declared the SNS topic and Subscription like below in my AWS Serverless Application Model template :-

```
MyTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: !Sub 'test-${Environment}-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}'
      Tags:
       - Key: Environment
         Value: !FindInMap [Environment, FullForm, !Ref Environment]
      TopicName: !Sub 'test-${Environment}-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}'

  MySubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Endpoint: !Ref SubscriptionEndPoint
      Protocol: !Ref SubscriptionProtocol
      Region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      TopicArn: !Ref MyTopic
```

And then using the SNS Topic ARN in my Lambda function's environment as following in the same template file :-

```
MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Environment:
        Variables:
          RUNTIME_SNS_TOPIC_ARN: !GetAtt MyTopic.Arn
```

Outputs (in SAM template):-

```
MyTopic:
    Description: SNS Topic for the Ingest to send notification to
    Export:
      Name: !Sub
        - ${ExportPrefix_}:${AWS::Region}:MyTopic
        - ExportPrefix_: !If
          - HasExportPrefix
          - !Join ['-', [!Ref ExportPrefix, !Ref Environment]]
          - !Join ['-', [!Select [0, !Split ["-", !Ref "AWS::StackName"]], !Ref Environment]]
      Value: !Sub "${MyTopic.Arn}:${MyTopic.Version.Version}"
  MySubscription:
    Description: Subscription to get messages from a topic
    Export:
      Name: !Sub
        - ${ExportPrefix_}:${AWS::Region}:MySubscription
        - ExportPrefix_: !If
          - HasExportPrefix
          - !Join ['-', [!Ref ExportPrefix, !Ref Environment]]
          - !Join ['-', [!Select [0, !Split ["-", !Ref "AWS::StackName"]], !Ref Environment]]
      Value: !Sub "${MySubscription.Arn}:${MySubscription.Version.Version}"
```

However, I'm getting following error :-

**13:30:30  Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: my-stack, ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Template error: resource MyTopic does not support attribute type Arn in Fn::GetAtt**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `AWS::SNS:Topic` returns the ARN when you use `Ref`

Check out the [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html#aws-properties-sns-topic-return-values) on the return values.

Try with

```yaml
MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Environment:
        Variables:
          RUNTIME_SNS_TOPIC_ARN: !Ref MyTopic  # Using !Ref
```

Comment: Im getting this error :- TopicArn Reason: An ARN must have at least 6 elements, not 1

Comment: Is this a Cloudformation error, or an error within your Lambda function?

Comment: sorry. my bad. your solution is fine. I overread your solution and referred the topic like this !Ref MyTopic.Arn instead of just !Ref MyTopic. The .Arn does not work and the error was due to that. Your solution worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see some of these errors inline while authoring templates:

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

```sh
[cfn-lint] E1010: Invalid GetAtt MyTopic.Arn for resource MyLambda
[cfn-lint] E1019: Parameter MyTopic.Arn for Fn::Sub not found at Outputs/MyTopic/Value/Fn::Sub
[cfn-lint] E1019: Parameter MyTopic.Version.Version for Fn::Sub not found at Outputs/MyTopic/Value/Fn::Sub
[cfn-lint] E1019: Parameter MySubscription.Arn for Fn::Sub not found at Outputs/MySubscription/Value/Fn::Sub
[cfn-lint] E1019: Parameter MySubscription.Version.Version for Fn::Sub not found at Outputs/MySubscription/Value/Fn::Sub
```

It'll also point out that `Value` needs to be indented less in the [`Outputs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html)

---

[`AWS::SNS::Topic` return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html#aws-properties-sns-topic-return-values)

[`AWS::SNS::Subscription`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html)